# Create a view to merge all data from 2 tables

Tags: sql, view, oracle11g, merge, outer-join

Tables A and B have N columns with the same name (Common columns), each table has its own special columns - table A has X additional columns and table B has Y additional columns. Column1* - is DB-wide unique ID, so rows in tables A and B cannot be merged. We need to create a viewAB which would include all data in tables A and B.

We tried UNION ALL (but it puts data from different columns to a single column if we do not name all columns), FULL OUTER JOIN did not help because in the view we could see Common columns appear twice (i.e. Column1 and Column1_1 etc). The ideal solution is to make the query in which we do not need to name Common columns (there are a lot), but it is fine if we have them named.

See the picture how we would like to see our data (https://i.stack.imgur.com/5erX6.jpg).

Please, find below the scripts to set up the tables A and B.

```
--tableA

CREATE TABLE tableA
(
  Common1 varchar2(50),
  Common2 varchar2(50),
  Common3 varchar2(50),
  A1 varchar2(50),
  A2 varchar2(50),
  A3 varchar2(50),
  CONSTRAINT Common1_pk PRIMARY KEY (Common1)
);

INSERT INTO tableA (Common1, Common2, Common3, A1, A2, A3) VALUES ( '1C1', '1C2', '1C3', '1A1', '1A2', '1A3');
INSERT INTO tableA (Common1, Common2, Common3, A1, A2, A3) VALUES ( '2C1', '2C2', '2C3', '2A1', '2A2', '2A3');
INSERT INTO tableA (Common1, Common2, Common3, A1, A2, A3) VALUES ( '3C1', '3C2', '3C3', '3A1', '3A2', '3A3');

--tableB

CREATE TABLE tableB
(
  Common1 varchar2(50),
  Common2 varchar2(50),
  Common3 varchar2(50),
  B1 varchar2(50),
  B2 varchar2(50),
  B3 varchar2(50),
  B4 varchar2(50),
  CONSTRAINT Common1B_pk PRIMARY KEY (Common1)
);

INSERT INTO tableB (Common1, Common2, Common3, B1, B2, B3, B4) VALUES ( '1C1B', '1C2B', '1C3B', '1B1', '1B2', '1B3', '1B4');
INSERT INTO tableB (Common1, Common2, Common3, B1, B2, B3, B4) VALUES ( '2C1B', '2C2B', '2C3B', '2B1', '2B2', '2B3', '2B4');
INSERT INTO tableB (Common1, Common2, Common3, B1, B2, B3, B4) VALUES ( '3C1B', '3C2B', '3C3B', '3B1', '3B2', '3B3', '3B4');
INSERT INTO tableB (Common1, Common2, Common3, B1, B2, B3, B4) VALUES ( '4C1B', '4C2B', '4C3B', '4B1', '4B2', '4B3', '4B4');


--viewAB
--(  
--  Common1 varchar2(50),
--  Common2 varchar2(50),
--  Common3 varchar2(50),
--  A1 varchar2(50),
--  A2 varchar2(50),
--  A3 varchar2(50),
--  B1 varchar2(50),
--  B2 varchar2(50),
--  B3 varchar2(50),
--  B4 varchar2(50)
--)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify all the columns (you can't use `select *` as you've already found), and `union all` the data from the two tables. What you might be missing is to include placeholders for the columns from the other table in each part of the union. For example:

```
SELECT common1, common2, common3,
  a1, a2, a3,
  null AS b1, null AS b2, null AS b3, null AS b4
FROM tableA
UNION ALL
SELECT common1, common2, common3,
  null AS a1, null AS a2, null AS a3,
  b1, b2, b3, b4
FROM tableB
```

Because you have null values with no data type, you may need to cast the, to `varchar2`, at least in the first part, e.g.

```
CAST (null AS varchar2(50)) AS b1, ...
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0e62b/1).

Comment: Thank you, Alex, this approach seems to work fine. If we do not find a way to achieve the same without mentioning all columns we shall implement it this way. It is not perfect for us, as we have ~100-150 columns in tables A and B, and new columns may appear weekly, so maintaining this view will require some time.. Thank you for the SQL Fiddle link - I was looking for similar demo tool for weeks=)

Comment: @ivang - you could write a PL/SQL block (or stored proc) to generate the view source code from the data dictionary, using dynamic SQL. But if the columns change then code that refers to the view will be changing too, and maintaining the view would be part of the schema maintenance, perhaps.

Comment: Thank you, we decided to do exactly like you suggested, it seems that this is the best option.